# bash: child can not get its PID correctly

Tags: linux, bash

why is this that when I run the script below, both parent and child think they have the same pid?

```
#!/bin/bash

foo ()
{
    while true
    do
        sleep 5
        echo child: I am $$
    done
}


( foo ) &

echo parent: I am $$ and child is $!

>./test.sh
parent: I am 26542 and child is 26543
>child: I am 26542
child: I am 26542
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Bash, there are `$$` and `$BASHPID` variables that are somewhat confusing. `$$` is a process ID of the script itself. `$BASHPID` is a process ID of the current instance of Bash. These things are not the same, but often give the same results. In your case, you used that incorrectly. Replacing `$$` with `$BASHPID` in function `foo` will solve the problem.

See [Internal Variables](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html) section of [Bash Advanced Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) for more details.

Comment: thanks. What's interesting is that the child gives 26542 when the parent has exited, and there's nobody by that pid in ps. I wonder what's the semantics of that?